# Python requests handle JSON output

Tags: python, json, api, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to query API to get a JSON response, the following is my code.

```
import requests

query_url = 'https://IP-Address/api/v1/request'

data = {"token":"8f86788b04637676b1f66eed902", "query":"days>50", "type":"json", "size":10}
response = requests.post(query_url, json=data, verify=False)

print(response.json())
```

I'm getting the following error,

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I also have a option to have **CSV** as **"type"** instead of JSON.

I created this Python request from cURL, which works good and outputs a JSON data. The following is the cURL command.

```
curl -kv -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'https://IP-Address/api/v1/request' -d '{"token":"64bd230a775656a739b4673eb18", "query":"days>50", "type":"json", "size":10}'
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Are you getting a 200 response code from api query? What does response.text output?

Comment: It is most probably in this line `print(response.json())`. There reason is that the response is not in the json format. Please, post the output of `response.text`

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov and SuperShoot. True, i'm getting the output when I print **response.text**, but how do I interpret as JSON as I need to print certain fields. Is that possible?

Comment: @Karthik what is the output of `response.text`?

Comment: [{ "data": "Karthik", "classification": "public", "detail": "Tag1, Tag2, Tag3", "days": 70, "date_last": "2017-07-21 05:48:07 AM" }]

Comment: The error message states that the first character is not a character JSON data can start with. You should get a more technical representation of the content, try `print(response.content)` or `print([response.text])` and have look at the first character.